# 'To' or 'For' usage in this context

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct,

> Obesity can occur whether to male or female, ***to*** all ages, race and to the whole ethnic group.

or

> Obesity can occur whether to male or female, ***for*** all ages, race and to the whole ethnic group.

I personally prefer 'to'. It's kind of 'addressed to'

Comment: Did you mean to repeat "Which is correct" at the beginning of each sentence?

Comment: Yes, so To or For..

Comment: Sorry about the comment up there, I mean: Yes, so To or For.., I need an explanation for the 'to' and 'for' whether it addresses the message correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather say "Obesity can occur either to a male or a female ***of*** any age, race or to the (whole) ethnic group."

Comment: Hello V.V thanks for your answer. What do you think, if we change this sentence to: Obesity can occur to a male and a female, all ages, race and to the whole ethnic group.

Comment: Could you kindly explain about the 'of' usage in this sentence? And can we just use male or female without 'a'? Thanks

Comment: @Fionne. Lets analyse the words. Obesity can occur to a person (a male or a female ), can't it? To a group (people). But just logically age and race cannot become  overweight. The article is used before nouns, you know, but if you use "male or female " as adjectives, there's no article.

Comment: I understand now, so male and female can be used as an adjectives. What do you think the two sentences above? Is it grammatically correct or incorrect? i checked it and it turned out there was no error.